# Passing external values to the react component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to make the Dancing Bars for level indication. The values for the level are coming from the server(outside of the components tree). I have dynamically created the Dancing Bars component and wants to update the current level in milliseconds.

Below is my try to achieve one.

```
var global;

function changeValue(value){
     global = value; //Getting the updated value
}

class DancingBars extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.forceUpdate.bind(this), 40);  // forcely update the component at this rate
    }
    render() {
       if(global === undefined){
          global = 50;  //Set default value
       }
        return (
            <LevelMeter fillColor={global}></LevelMeter>
        );
    }
}
```

As seen in my code, I am getting the updated value in `changeValue() function` and pass it to the DancingBars component through the `global variable`. Initially when DancingBars component is mounted on the DOM then the component is forcely updated with some rate(changeable), the global var is undefined in render. So I wrote that comparison code to set default level when values are not coming yet. When values are starting to change then it will automatically update the level and works smoothly.

But this is not a good way to that as I am not able to drive it through an event because it starts when component is mounted and consumes more **CPU Cycles** which is wasted and not good. I have also tried it through the `redux state`, but it updates drastically slow and which also not a good idea. I dont want the performance to reduce.

I have created the DancingBars component dynamically with `array map function` and I am also using redux for state management. As the values are real-time and I don't want to store it in the redux state.

Is there a simple way to do like when the value changes in changeValue() function then and then only DancingBars component should re-render? Or how do I caught the event of value change in changeValue() function and pass the value as props to DancingBars component, and do something with shouldComponentUpdate life-cycle method?

Answer (score 0):

- move initialization outside of `render()`
- force rerendering only if value changes

F.e.:

```
class DancingBars extends React.Component {
  state = {
    level: global === undefined ? 50 : global
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 40);  
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {    
    clearInterval(this.interval);  
  }

  // no binding needed
  tick = () => {
    if(global && (global != this.state.level)) setState({ level: global });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <LevelMeter fillColor={this.state.level}></LevelMeter>
    );
  }
}
```

You can try to use hooks (functional components), like [this](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)

Instead of redux you can try to use `mobx` (observables). Mobx is a bit slower then redux.

You can/should use sockets and update only when data arrives.

Comment: thanks for your replay. Your logic works. As per your logic setInterval timer keeps going when the page is loaded. This will not take so much CPU Percentages, but I think there is some way to construct logic such that when the value gets for the first time or changes then and then only setInterval timer should start.

Comment: I updated the answer code a bit - additional condition in `tick` to cover starting `global` (undefined value) difference to default 50 (saved at start in constructor). There is no other way to repeatedly check external values and react/rerender on changes. Only using sockets can be more optimal.